# Apache Thrift 0.9.0 won't configure per instructions

Tags: centos, thrift

Apache Thrift 0.9.0 won't configure per instructions on base CentOS install. When you try to do the ./configure, it gives you an "Error: libcrypto required"

The documentation says that you need:

```
sudo yum install automake libtool flex bison pkgconfig gcc-c++ boost-devel libevent-devel zlib-devel python-devel ruby-devel
```

http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/centos/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is missing the openssl dependency, you also need to include:

openssl-devel.x86_64 in your package install list above

What you really need to install is

```
sudo yum install automake libtool flex bison pkgconfig gcc-c++ boost-devel libevent-devel zlib-devel python-devel ruby-devel openssl-devel.x86_64
```

Or just this if you've already installed the above per the original instructions.

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel.x86_64
```