# Issue Statically Compiling Thrift 0.9.0 on Centos 6.5

Tags: static, thrift, centos6

I'm working to compile the Thrift 0.9.0 binary statically in a CentOS VM. I get the issue that the libthrift.a binary is not being created. I am using a vagrant box to run centos:
https://github.com/2creatives/vagrant-centos/releases/download/v6.5.1/centos65-x86_64-20131205.box

Once I ssh to the vagrant box I run the following commands:

```
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/thrift/0.9.0/thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz
cd thrift-0.9.0
./configure --enable-static
make
```

This will run but I ran a find command (sudo find / -name "*.a")  on the system to see if there was any ".a" files made and the only file that was made was "libparse.a" which doesn't seem right. From my understanding it should be "libthrift.a".

Searching through the config.log file it says that it does want to build the static libraries:

```
configure:11944: checking whether to build static libraries
configure:11948: result: yes
```

Looking at more locations in the log file that has the keyword "static" reveals potential places that may be errors.

```
configure:9028: checking if gcc static flag -static works
configure:9056: result: no

configure:13915: checking if g++ static flag -static works
configure:13943: result: no

lt_cv_prog_compiler_static_works=no
lt_cv_prog_compiler_static_works_CXX=no
```

The full log file is here: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/449460/staticThriftErrorLog.rtf

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just in case it was just a versioning issue, I just tried updating everything using yum (sudo yum update) and ran into the same problems after successfully updating.

Comment: Even after installing the dependencies mentioned in another stack overflow answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388135/apache-thrift-0-9-0-wont-configure-per-instructions) the static problems still exist.

Comment: Have you tried the same with Thrift trunk? I remember some issues on CentOS that have been recently fixed. I'm not sure about the details, don't use CentOS so much. Anyway, if you think you found a problem, please feel free to post the mailing list and/or file a JIRA ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to generate the libthrift.a file. After running the command for the extra dependancies mentioned in my comment I forgot to run the make command. So after doing the make command I found the libthrift.a file in "thrift-0.9.0/lib/cpp/.libs/". Interestingly enough, even after fixing the dependencies, config.log still had the same potential problem areas regarding the gcc/g++ static flag and static compiler.

Specifically the dependency command is as follows:

```
sudo yum install automake libtool flex bison pkgconfig gcc-c++ boost-devel libevent-devel zlib-devel python-devel ruby-devel openssl-devel.x86_64
```

Edit: After getting advice on the Jira ticket, it turns out the specific vagrant box I was using was causing the errors. Using the VM he linked I was able to successfully build Thrift using the provided instructions. (Jira ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2559)

Comment: If (1) that's different from what is listed on http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/centos and (2) if it still applies to trunk => may I ask you to file a JIRA ticket with your findings?

Comment: The packages I needed in oder to get thrift to build on centos 6.5 does appear to be different than what is listed on the site you linked. I'm relatively new to this community, is the trunk build different than this tar ball https://archive.apache.org/dist/thrift/0.9.0/thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz? That is the tar ball I used. Also what is the link to the Jira project?

Comment: [Last release](http://thrift.apache.org/download) was 0.9.1 in summer 2013. Trunk can be [retrieved via git](http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift.git),  JIRA can be found [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT). See also [how to contribute](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute). Thanks!

Comment: I am submitting a bug report now. Actually with the latest trunk version it does not "make" at all on centos 6.5. That is following the directions in the centos setup you linked. I tried it with both the packages listed and also with the packages that made 0.9.0 work for me.

Comment: I just made the bug report here is the link [link] (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2559). If there is anything you think I should change or add please let me know and I'll take care of it.